Parent and child or flat structure - are both normalized?
I am designing a system that records stock transactions for a product. Some product types record items by serial number for traceability, some products types do not serialize items.
When recording stock transactions, I could see designing the ledger in two ways: 1) Recording by product (the parent), and then linking to a child table for serial numbers when required, or 2) Recording by the most granular entity, either a product by itself or a parent and serial combo when required.
Below is a picture clarifying the structure.
Is one normalized and the other not?
If they both are normal and it's a matter of preference based on the needs of the system and user?
Is there an objectively better method based on normalization rules?
Do such rules have guidance on this on this scenario?
If they do not, and either option would work, what considerations must be taken into account when deciding between the two approaches?


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking
a question? An ERD is a picture of DDL.

Ask exactly 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. "Normalized" with no other specifics doesn't mean anythiing in particular. Also "1NF" means nothing specific. Define what you mean. Also questions about normalization are faqs. How are you 1st stuck? Otherwise you are just asking for yet another presentation & a bespoke tutorial with no details about what you do or don't understand or misunderstand. [ask] [Help]

There is no "best" in engineering. What is "better" for you here & how are you stuck evaluating here? Strategy for “Which is
better” questions

Delete the concept of "serial bundle id" and use transaction id as the foreign key:
create table transaction (
  id int primary key,
  product_id int not null references product,
  quantity int not null
);

create table serial (
  id int primary key,
  transaction_id int not null references transaction,
  quantity int not null
)

Note that it's best practice to name the primary key simply id for all tables. We don't prefix other columns with the name of the table, eg transaction_quantity, and the id column should be no exception.
